Ubuntu 24.04 LTS - virtual screen over two monitors
I'm writing because I need your help.
I'm running a lenovo with multiple outputs but only two (DP-1 and HDMI-3) are connected.
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

for the screen I've used in the past "xrandr".
$ xrandr --prop 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0022f0492901010101
        32150104a5331d78261e55a059569f27
        0d5054a1080081c081809500b300d1c0
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500fd1e1100001e000000fd00324c18
        5e11000a202020202020000000fc0048
        50204c41323330360a202020000000ff
        003343513135304e354b310a202000b8
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    subconnector: Native 
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 236 
        supported: 236
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 249 
        supported: 249
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    subconnector: Unknown 
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 255 
        supported: 255
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 263 
        supported: 263
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0022f04a2901010101
        2415010380331d782e01f5a257529f27
        0a5054a1080081c081809500b300d1c0
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500fe1f1100001e000000fd00324c18
        5e11000a202020202020000000fc0048
        50204c41323330360a202020000000ff
        00434e43313336305456360a20200043
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 267 
        supported: 267
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    subconnector: Unknown 
        supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 271 
        supported: 271
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 279 
        supported: 279
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
$
$

more information with inxi:
$ inxi -Fz
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Mini-pc System: LENOVO product: 11T300BLGE v: ThinkCentre M70q Gen 3
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 330B v: NOK serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO
    v: M43KT2DA date: 08/28/2024
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 12th Gen Intel Core i3-12100T bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    cache: L2: 5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1633 min/max: 800/4100 cores: 1: 3533 2: 1854 3: 2186
    4: 1590 5: 800 6: 800 7: 837 8: 1470
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,swrast platforms: x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
    renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 730 (ADL-S GT1)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-S HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-45-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I219-LM driver: e1000e
  IF: eno2 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 119.24 GiB used: 14.68 GiB (12.3%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Lenovo model: UMIS RPJTJ128MKP1MDY
    size: 119.24 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 116.32 GiB used: 14.65 GiB (12.6%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 22.3 MiB (4.4%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 32.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Info:
  Memory: total: 8 GiB available: 7.44 GiB used: 2.45 GiB (32.9%)
  Processes: 294 Uptime: 9h 1m Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.34
$
$

I've used the following command in the past (Raspberry Pi) to merge both monitors into one big virtual display:
xrandr --setmonitor Virtual auto HDMI-1,HDMI-2
=>
therefore I've adapted this to the current setup:
xrandr --setmonitor bigone auto DP-1,HDMI-3
and this is the output of the cli:
$ xrandr --setmonitor bigone auto DP-1,HDMI-3
output list DP-1,HDMI-3
add monitor DP-1
output name DP-1
add monitor HDMI-3
output name HDMI-3
$ 
$
$
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
$
$

i'm now a bit at a loss and would therefore like your help on how i can solve the problem....
Thanks in advance!
